# gpuocelot llvm/Assembly/Parser.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, llvm

I am using ubuntu 12.04
I have been trying to install gpuocelot for a few day now. 
I recently installed llvm from the svn using

svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm­project/llvm/trunk llvm
./configure ­­enable­optimized
sudo make
sudo make install

But to do this I had to update gcc to 4.7 which i had also done

Now when i run sudo ./build.py --install

I keep on getting the following error
ocelot/ocelot/ir/implementation/ExternalFunctionSet.cpp:28:34: fatal error: llvm/Assembly/Parser.h: No such file or directory

The following outputs might be of help

z

```
aid@zaid-lappy:~/gpuocelot$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0

zaid@zaid-lappy:~/gpuocelot$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.7.3
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

zaid@zaid-lappy:~/gpuocelot$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.7.3
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

zaid@zaid-lappy:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/l/checkout/gpuocelot/ocelot/build_local/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin

 echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64:

echo $LIBRARY_PATH returns blank
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LLVM C++ API, including the very existence and location of headers, is very unstable. This is why projects usually align themselves to some official *release* of LLVM, and I'm sure GPUOcelot follows the same pattern.

In top-of-tree LLVM, the header `llvm/Assembler/Parse.h` doesn't exist, which is why you can't find it. You should compile & link GPUOcelot vs. the LLVM version it supports officially. If GPUOcelot tries to follow the top-of-tree of LLVM, at least there should be a "known good revision" with which it works.

Comment: [The installation guide says](https://github.com/gtcasl/gpuocelot/wiki/Installation#cpu-target) _The CPU target requires LLVM to be installed. Ocelot has been tested with LLVM release 3.4._